# Non abelian group of order $p^n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product, direct-product

Construct a non abelian group $G$ of order $p^n$(infact n>2) such that $G$ is not direct product of any of its  two subgroups.

I think we have to use semi direct product and the fact that G has at least one normal subgroup of each possible order.Moreover such subgroup intersect $Z(G)$ nontrivially.

Comment: There are no such groups for $n = 1, 2$.

Comment: right.i am assuming n>2.edited now

Comment: any nonabelian group of order $p^3$ has this property.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $|\operatorname{Aut}(C_{p^{n-1}})| = \varphi(p^{n-1}) = p^{n-2} (p-1)$ [this is where we used $n>2]$, so by Cauchy's theorem there is an element of order $p$, which generates $C_p$, which gives a semidirect product $C_{p^{n-1}} \rtimes C_p$ of order $p^n$.